# Is Hadoop High Availibility possible with Journal Node separate than Name Node?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In Hadoop high availability implementation, is it necessary to keep journal node on Active Name Node?

**Can the Journal Node operate on a different Node than the one working as Active Name Node**; How will the Name Node communicate with the Journal Node while both being physically different hosts?

Comment: They communicate over RPC, probably, or some similar protocol

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Journal Node(s) can be on different node, other than NameNode. Both the services communicate over [RPC](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopRpc)